# Twitter API: current_user_retweet not seen even with include_my_retweet=1 option

Tags: api, twitter, media

Am working with retweet feature with Twitter API. I currently need to check if a current tweet has already been retweeted by a given user. I checked the doc, twitter has options to check the retweet_count, but does not say retweeted by whom?

Is there a way to find that? Suppose a given tweet has 10 for retweeted_count i need to find the 10 users who had retweeted it Or is there a way to find if the current user has retweeted the tweet by passing the user_id or screen name.

I am slightly aware that there is a data point, current_user_retweet but for some reason am not able to get that. Is there any parameters other than include_my_retweet, that should be added to get this data point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the Re-tweeted by feature of the API

I'm copying and pasting the following from Twitter engineer Marcel Molina.

> We've just deployed two new resources for the retweet API:
>
> - /statuses/:status_id/retweeted_by
> - /statuses/:status_id/retweeted_by/ids
>
> The first will return up to the first 100 user representations of those who  have retweeted the
>   tweet specified in the url by :status_id.  The second will return just
>   the ids of those retweeters for the cases where  that's all you care
>   about.  Though up to the first 100 users will be returned by default,
>   these  resources both support the :count and :page parameters if you'd
>   like to pull  down fewer users. It should be noted though that for
>   operational efficiency  you can't use the :count and :page parameters
>   to go *beyond* the first 100  retweeters.
>
> Full docs here: 
>   http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-GET-statuses-id...
>   http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-GET-statuses-id...
>
> In conjunction with these additions we also want to provide a 
>   "retweet_count" parameter in the status payload for convenience. The
>   code  for this is mostly done but there are some details around cache
>   invalidation  that will likely push out the availability of the
>   retweet_count parameter  for a few weeks while we work on an
>   infrastructure change to obviate these  cache invalidation issues. But
>   we just wanted to give you a heads up about  that too!  P.S. Thanks to
>   everyone for weighing in on the naming of these resources ( 
>   http://twitter.com/twitterapi/status/10538921196) 
>   --  Marcel Molina  Twitter Platform Team  http://twitter.com/noradio

more information can be found here in the Twitter API google group:

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/226a38d3002d7cb6

Comment: There is a field retweeted that is returned in the json of https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2.This example was in twitter API doc. The result of the doc says, retweeted count = 25 but retweeted = false. Is this retweeted only for the current authenticated user?

Comment: No, this call is un-authenticated. You can test this by logging out of Twitter and clicking the link. Take note of the `&screen_name=` param.